# How debug/log errors on production services worker installation

Tags: service-worker

We have been using services worker on our mobile web app from some time now.
We use Sentry as event logs tool.
We are getting lot of error of the type:

- Cannot update a null/nonexistent service worker registration
- Error: AbortError: Failed to update a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://www.some.production.domain/') with script ('https://www.some.production.domain/sw.js'): Timed out while trying to start the Service Worker.

And so,

Is there a standard way to know why and if we should be worried about those kind of errors?

Or even get more details to try to figure out why they happen apparently in a random way?